# Creating an object from a nested array with frequency of key as object value

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an object, such that the keys will contain each unique element in my array, while the value will be the frequency in which the key appears as the 1th index element in a nested array. Using this example:

```
const test = [[1,3],[2,3],[3,6],[5,6],[5,7],[4,5],[4,8],[4,9],[10,4],[10,9]]
```

I expect to produce this

```
{
  '1': 0,
  '2': 0,
  '3': 2,
  '4': 1,
  '5': 1,
  '6': 2,
  '7': 1,
  '8': 1,
  '9': 2,
  '10': 0
}
```

However, this is what my code produces:

```
{
  '1': 0,
  '2': 0,
  '3': 0,
  '4': 0,
  '5': 0,
  '6': 0,
  '7': 0,
  '8': 0,
  '9': 0,
  '10': 0
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const result = {}
for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
    result[test[i][0]] = result[test[i][1]] ? result[test[i][0]] + 1  : 0
    result[test[i][1]] = result[test[i][1]] ? result[test[i][0]] + 1  : 0
}
```

Comment: what is with all of the first values of the nested array?

Comment: @NinaScholz I to create an object that will keep track of how frequently the first values in each array appear as the second value.

Comment: it is still unclear, what the first value is good for.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the left value as key, as well as the ruight value and count only the right value.

```js
const
    pairs = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 6], [5, 6], [5, 7], [4, 5], [4, 8], [4, 9], [10, 4], [10, 9]],
    counts = pairs.reduce((c, [l, r]) => {
        c[l] ??= 0;
        c[r] ??= 0;
        c[r]++;
        return c;
    }, {});

console.log(counts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```